# SQL Error OLE.INTEROP

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error whenever I load Management Studio or open a folder in the server explorer, etc. Additionally, If I try to create a new database it constantly is updating and does not finish. I have attached a screenshot of the error. Please let me know what I can do to fix this because it's really aggravating.

[Error Screen http://frickinsweet.com/databaseError.gif](http://frickinsweet.com/databaseError.gif)

Comment: This looks like the error you are having..

http://www.cto20.com/cto20/tabid/647/EntryID/53/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN forum http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=120476&SiteID=1

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be Client Tool corruption.

I've occasionally had to uninstall my client tools and reinstall them. Boot after uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the registry file AND re-run "regsvr32 actxprxy.dll"  This was a really odd and painful error. It only seemed to come into existence after installing VS SP1 but I really don't see why that would have happened.